# Laravel 5.3: Combining Arrays into One

Tags: arrays, laravel, request

A form is return 3 arrays due to a dynamic form which clones table rows on demand. I need to combine into a single array. I am not sure how to get the array with the most elements for a for loop because if some of the optional fields are entered, there are null values.

so, for example, the $request contains this:

```
witness: [
    "Bo Peep",
    "Potato Head",
    "Buzz Lightyear"
],
witness_email: [
    "bp@pixar.com",
    "ph@pixar.com",
    "bl@pixar.com"
],
witness_phone: [
   "(800) 555-1212",
   "8005551313",
   "800.555.1414"
]
```

How would I turn that into

```
witnesses: [
    {witness: "Bo Peep", email: "bp@pixar.com", phone: "(800) 555-1212"},
    {witness: "Potato Head", email: "ph@pixar.com", phone: "8005551313"},
    {witness: "Buzz Lightyear", email: "bl@pixar.com", phone: "800.555.1414"},
]
```

or something that I can loop over in a @foreach in the view?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this result an instance of Collection class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$new_array = [];
for($x = 0;$x < count($array['witness']); $x++) {
    $new_data['witness'] = $array['witness'];
    $new_data['email'] = $array['witness_email'];
    $new_data['phone'] = $array['witness_phone'];

    $new_array[] = $new_data;
}
```

If you want it to json, you can use:

```
$new_array = [];
for($x = 0;$x < count($array['witness']); $x++) {
    $new_data['witness'] = $array['witness'];
    $new_data['email'] = $array['witness_email'];
    $new_data['phone'] = $array['witness_phone'];

    $new_array[] = $new_data;
}
json_encode($new_array);
```

Now you have your new array (`$new_array`) with the data you want.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

If you can adjust your front end to add an index to the new generated rows, then it might be useful to generate the input names like this: `key[index][subkey]`.

For example:

```html
<!-- Row with index 0 -->
<input type="text" name="witnesses[0][witness]">
<input type="text" name="witnesses[0][email]">
<input type="text" name="witnesses[0][phone]">

<!-- Row with index 1 -->
<input type="text" name="witnesses[1][witness]">
<input type="text" name="witnesses[1][email]">
<input type="text" name="witnesses[1][phone]">

<!-- Row with index 2 -->
<input type="text" name="witnesses[2][witness]">
<input type="text" name="witnesses[2][email]">
<input type="text" name="witnesses[2][phone]">
```

Then your POST would contain a `witnesses` key like this:

```php
"witnesses" => [
  0 => [
    "witness" => "Name1",
    "email" => "Email1",
    "phone" => "Phone1",
  ],
  1 => [
    "witness" => "Name2",
    "email" => "Email2",
    "phone" => "Phone2",
  ],
  2 => [
    "witness" => "Name3",
    "email" => "Email3",
    "phone" => "Phone3",
  ],
]
```

And if some of fields aren't posted as you said (Think it would only happen for checkboxes/radioboxes and disabled fields though, otherwise they would just be an empty string), then I think you would have to do this, otherwise you will not be able to know which values belong to which row with the way you're doing it now :)

For example if you get the following in the post, then you wouldn't know who of the witnesses that does not have an email and/or phone number :)

```json
witness: [
  "Bo Peep",
  "Potato Head",
  "Buzz Lightyear",
  "Woody",
  "Andy"
],
witness_email: [
  "bp@pixar.com",
  "ph@pixar.com",
  "bl@pixar.com"
],
witness_phone: [
  "(800) 555-1212",
  "8005551313",
  "800.555.1414"
]
```